# HEROKU logs - tail react application

Tags: heroku

HEROKU logs. That only shows me about 100 lines. Is there not a way to see complete logs for our application on HEROKU?

Answer (score 0):

from `heroku logs help`:
-n, --num=num        number of lines to display
or using heroku web dashboard - logs addon